# how to make txt file in javascript using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, text

```
render(){
return(
  <div>
    <h2> word : {this.state.value} </h2>
    <button onClick={this.handleClick}> Click </button>
    <list>1</list>
    <textarea placeholder="(50 words over)" rows={10} style={{ width: '100%' }}/>
  </div>
);
```

}

How to save text in textarea into local txt file ?

Comment: First hit on duckduckgo, third hit on google, for "make browser generate a file for saving": https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/write-file-p